# how to create directory path which contains space

Tags: android, file-io, runtimeexception

Every time when my app tries to create a directory on SD card, it throws runtime exception.
The error is

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create library directory /storage/sdcard0/Seafile/logan676@163.com (cloud.seafile.com)/personal folder
```

So my question is if it is allowed to create directories which contains space.
And I implemented the code like below.

```
if (path != null) {
        // Has record in database
        repoDir = new File(path);
        if (!repoDir.exists()) {
            if (!repoDir.mkdirs()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Could not create library directory " + path);
            }
        }
        return path;
    }
```

I have to create such kind of directories because I deleted them when user clear caches.

```
/**
 * Deletes cache directory under a specific account<br>
 * remember to clear cache from database after called this method
 *
 * @param dirPath
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static void clearCache(String dirPath) throws IOException {
    // clear all cached files inside of the directory, the directory itself included
    File cacheDir = new File(dirPath);
    FileUtils.deleteDirectory(cacheDir);

}
```

This clearCache method will delete the root directory and its sub-directories.
So does it have anything to do with the runtime exceptions above.

Comment: Do you have write storage permission in your manifest?

Comment: yes, I have. I statement like this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: Is the path hardcoded or generated using Environment.getXXXDirectory() methods?

Comment: it was generated by `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Comment: As an aside-  its considered bad form on *nix OSes (which Android is one of) to use spaces in filenames-  it makes it harder to do command line manipulation of the file correctly.

Comment: The answer here is DON'T. You really don't want spaces in your path.

Comment: Try escaping the spaces in path. Like path = path.replace(" ","\\ ");